# how to handle bad request web api core with custome message?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a similar problem.
Is there a simpler way to handle the input data type errors?

https://coderethinked.com/customizing-automatic-http-400-error-response-in-asp-net-core-web-apis/

I searched but found no answer.

**Update:**

I found a solution from Microsoft's example:

```
 return BadRequest (new {message = "Something went wrong"});
```

But
When field is in **[Required]** model, error 400 is called before running the service. Is there a way to resolve the 400 error from the handle model?

Comment: What are your expected result? Using `ProblemDetails` or just return your custom error message for `400` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718157/how-to-add-custom-cannot-deserialize-error-message-in-asp-net-core-2/59728990#59728990)? What do you mean  `a simpler way`?

Comment: I want return only `Message`. `{Message: "Error for ...."}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But When field is in [Required] model, error 400 is called before running the service. Is there a way to resolve the 400 error from the handle model?

The `[ApiController]` attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response.

To disable the automatic 400 behavior, set the `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property to true in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
      options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#disable-automatic-400-response